# Can the set method use a value of a different type?

Tags: c#, properties

I have class that holds an XDocument variable.  I want to be able to set this XDocument variable in another class in my program just by a string, the name of the XML Document.  Is it possible for the "value" variable in a set method to be something other than the type of the field?  Here is what I want to do:

Class1:

```
private XDocument _xDoc;
public XDocument XDoc
{

    get
    {
        return _xDoc;
    }
    set
    {
        if(_xDoc == null)
            _xDoc = GetXDocument(value);  //GetXDocument is a function that takes a string 
                                         //and returns the corresponding XDocument
    }
```

Class2:

```
Class1 myClass;
myClass.XDoc = "Name of XML File"
```

Is this something that is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of `value` will always be the type of your property.

You can use a method instead:

```
public void SetXDocument(string name)
{
     if(_xDoc == null)
        _xDoc = GetXDocument(value);
}

// usage
myClass.SetXDocument("Name of XML File");
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this in class 2:

```
Class1 myClass;
myClass.XDoc = myClass.GetXDocument("Name of XML File");
```